# access double click list open form

Tags: ms-access

I saw this in someone else's question but the solution didn't work for me.

I have a list box (List0). I want to be able to double click on an item in the list box and open a form (2017 Return Log) to the specific record clicked on (based on ID).

I was using this code and it worked, but for some reason it no longer does:

```
Dim strCriteria As String

strCriteria = "[ID] = " & Me.List0.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "2017 Return Log", , , strCriteria, , acDialog
```

Now, when I double click on an item in the list I get this error: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID] = '.

The Me.List0.Value evaluates as "null" when I step through it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it worked, but "no longer does". What does that mean? The event no longer triggers? The event triggers but the effect is not expected? There is no effect? Is there an error? Have you tried stepping through the code? How does `?Me.List0.Value` evaluate in the immediate window? Sorry for the questions, but there isn't enough information provided to give an answer. Please edit your question with more detail. Welcome to SO! [tour] [ask]

Comment: The only thing that I can think of that would have broken the code is changing the listbox from single to multi-select. Is it true that your listbox is multi-select?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Nz function to your code. This means that if the value of the listbox is null then your criteria string won't be empty.

```
strCriteria = "[ID] = " & Nz(Me.List0.Value, 0)
```

With this change, when the listbox value is null, 0 will be returned and you won't get the error. You could build upon this to show a message box instead of trying to open the form when the ID is absent.